# Load data infile in to oracle table using php

Tags: php, oracle

I want load data from text file to oracle database using php , what function to be used here to prevent this warning?

```
    $myFile = "local.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r') or die("Could not open: " . mysql_error());
    echo " file opened<br>";
    $sql ="LOAD DATA infile".$myFile. "INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by".'" ' ."(acc_nbr)";
    $result = odbc_execute($connect_cc,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query! ".odbc_errormsg());

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo " file has not been uploaded to database";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " File has been uploaded successfully to database";
    }

    fclose($fh);
```

> Warning: odbc_execute() expects parameter 2 to be array, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FTP\Monthly_Segmentation_process.php on line
>   59
>        Couldn't execute query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
LOAD DATA infile".$myFile. "INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed ...
```

looks like SQL*Loader's control file.

I don't think you can use it elsewhere.

It means that

- you have to call `SQLLDR.EXE`
- which will call the control file (such as `MY_LOAD.CTL`)
- which contains all those options you wrote above

Comment: Thank you , do you have any PHP reference related? how to call it?

Comment: No, sorry; I don't speak PHP.

Comment: Thank you , I have done it using php with shell_exec function.